# Swing drag and drop

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop

I would like to implement a game board in swing (needs to be a table, though about either `jtable` or `gridlayout` etc ...) where I will be able to drag and drop a picture on to this game board and all the cells that the picture fell on will get a notification that they were chosen.

Can anyone help with that? how do I get a couple of cells in a table know that an object was dropped on them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/index.html).

Comment: Helped a lot,Thanks! but I still need to know if I can drop an image on multiple cells of a jtable. for this there is no answer in the tutorial

Answer (score 7):

I think you have to spent some time with Google. I found the following with a little time with Google.

- [Introduction to DnD](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/intro.html)
- [How to drag and drop with Java 2, Part 1](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-03-1999/jw-03-dragndrop.html)
- [How to drag and drop with Java 2, Part 2](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-08-1999/jw-08-draganddrop.html)
- [Drag and Drop Effects](http://www.jroller.com/gfx/entry/drag_and_drop_effects_part)

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

[Read](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/intro.html) this and if you have an more specific questions come back and ask them.