# Drag and Drop JLabel

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, awt

I have a bunch of JLables in a JPanel, and I am using a FlowLayout on the JPanel. Each label is 100% the width of the JPanel, so as I add labels to the JPanel the are vertically placed. What I would like to be able to do is click and drag a JLabel up or down in the list. Using this code, I was expecting "Here" to be printed to the output console, but it was not. What do I need to do for drag and drop?

```
public class LayerItem extends JLabel{
    public LayerItem(){
        this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent evt){
                lblMouseDragged(evt);
            }
        });
    }

    public void lblMouseDragged(MouseEvent evt){
        System.out.println("Here");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change:

```
this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
```

To:

```
this.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter(){
```

Answer (score 1):

THe similar question like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8562743/swing-drag-and-drop).. By the way, I think you can use `TransferHandler`, like [this](http://www.roseindia.net/java/example/java/swing/SwingDragDrop.shtml)